# Changing wordpress menu code

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with a wordpress menu, here's the code i'm using:

```
<?php wp_page_menu( ); ?>
```

and this is the output:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
      <a href="http://blahblah.com/?page_id=1">Shoes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
      <a href="http://blahblah.com/?page_id=2">Accessories</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
      <a href="http://blahblah.com/?page_id=3">Watches</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
      <a href="http://blahblah.com/?page_id=4">Bags</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">Shoes</a>
  <a href="#">Accessories</a>
  <a href="#">Watches</a>
  <a href="#">Bags</a>
</nav>
```

Is this possible and how can I do this?

Comment: Look  at the `wp_page_menu()` function and amend the code

Comment: This may sound daft but how do i do that, i'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: It's probably in the functions file, can't actually remember, sorry!

Comment: no worries, at least that gives me a place to start

Comment: why you have used wp_page_menu() rather than using wp_nav_menu()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code

```
    <nav>
    <?php
        $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( '{type your menu name here}' );
        foreach ( $items as $item){
            echo '<a href="#">'.$item->title.'</a>';
        }
    ?>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, the thing is there is no menu name,  I want all the pages to show?

Comment: You can show all the pages by creating a menu and adding all pages to the menu.

Comment: I've just used your code in another part but I want to display thumbnails but it's not working, here's the bit of code i changed echo '<li><a href="#">'.$item->get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a></li>'; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for add menu in wordpress admin panal u have to add some code in your themes functions.php file,here is one exapmple:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'insert_data_page');

function insert_data_page() {

    add_menu_page(
        'My Menu',
        'ADD DATA',
        'administrator',
        'data_page',
        'page_data_insert'
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'data_page',              
        'ALL DATA',                
        'DATA',                
        'administrator',                   
        'data_page_all',    
        'page_data_all'            
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'data_page',              
        'DATATABLES SAMPLE',                
        'DATATABLES SAMPLE',                
        'administrator',                   
        'datatables',    
        'datatables_sample'            
    );
}
```

for this functions refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference